On the Singular Cardinal Hypothesis
I'm trying to find the proof of this result.
If for each $\lambda\geq2^\omega$, $\lambda^\omega\le\lambda^+$, then the SCH holds.
I'm not sure where to look. So if you have any info about this, please share it with me.

Are you familiar with Silver's theorem?

The one that states that for each singular cardinal of uncountable cofinality $\kappa$ if GCH holds below it then $2^\kappa=\kappa^+$?

Yes, a more general version of that statement can be proven to which a quick corollary is that if the SCH holds at every cardinal with countable cofinality, then the SCH holds (which is a stronger statement than the one you're asking about). You can find the details in Jech.

(Silver actually originally proved that if the GCH holds stationarily often below an uncountable cofinality singular $\kappa$, then GCH holds at $\kappa$. Since the strong limit cardinals of cofinality $\omega$ are stationary below any singular strong limit with higher cofinality, this shows that if all singular strong limit cardinals with cofinality $\omega$ satisfy GCH, then all singular strong limit cardinals do. This is a weak form of "SCH at countable cof -> SCH"... the version presented in Jech is more refined and works for the strong form of the SCH.)

So Is it enough to prove that $\lambda\ge2^\omega\implies\lambda^\omega\le\lambda^+$ for $\lambda$ singular cardinal of countable cofinality to get SCH?

I have seen papers where they say that it is enough to prove that for regular cardinals $\kappa>\omega_1$, $\kappa^\omega=\kappa$. And they argue that SCH follows from that combined with Silver's theorem but I can't see where the connection is

To your first, yes, it's even enough to prove $\lambda > 2^{\aleph_0}\to \lambda^{\aleph_0}\le\lambda^+$ for $\lambda$ singular and countable cofinality (and note in that case we'll always have $\lambda^{\aleph_0}>\lambda$ so we might as well write $=$ rather than $\le$ in the consequent). For the second, if we had some singular $\lambda$ with countable cofinality with $\lambda^{\aleph_0}>\lambda^+$, then $\lambda^+$ would be a regular cardinal $>\omega_1$ satisfying $(\lambda^+)^{\aleph_0}> \lambda^+.$

(And I guess to add to the first one, in that case note we'll also never have $\lambda = 2^{\aleph_0}$, so that corner case isn't relevant anyway. In general, the SCH for the cardinal $\kappa$ says $2^{\operatorname{cf}\kappa}<\kappa$ implies $\kappa^{\operatorname{cf}\kappa}=\kappa^+$ and it could be equivalently written $2^{\operatorname{cf}\kappa}\le \kappa$ implies $\kappa^{\operatorname{cf} \kappa}\le \kappa^+$, but that's just including additional cases that can't happen on both ends.)

Thank you so much, now everything makes more sense to me!
